# Filtering in DevExpress grid

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I'm trying to programmatically disable filtering for a specific column in the DevExpress grid in my wpf app.

I tried `column.AllowAutoFilter=false`, but no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind,I figured it out...I used AllowColumnFiltering=DefaultBoolean.False and it worked.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Refer the documentation for [AllowColumnFiltering](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridColumnBase_AllowColumnFilteringtopic) property.

> It allows or denies filtering of grid columns. If filtering is
>   disabled, FilterEditor will not be shown, regardless of the
>   [AllowFilterEditor](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataViewBase_AllowFilterEditortopic) property value. The [AllowFilterEditor](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataViewBase_AllowFilterEditortopic)
>   property makes sense only when filtering is enabled.

From: [Filtering Overview](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/6130/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Filtering-and-Searching/Filtering-Overview)

Individual columns provide the [ColumnBase.AllowColumnFiltering](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.ColumnBase.AllowColumnFiltering.property) property that allows the default behavior, specified by a View, to be overridden. For instance, you can prevent end-users from invoking the filter dropdowns of individual columns. When filtering by a column is disabled, its filter button is never displayed.

**References:**
[Disable Filter Dropdown and enable Filter Editor](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q425312/disable-filter-dropdown-and-enable-filter-editor)